# Who are the twins in Episode 1 of Durarara!!x2 Shou?

Tags: durarara

At first, I didn't notice this part because I was too focused on Celty and Shinra's "lovey-dovey upgrade", until my friend told me about this part...

They are making something weird, or should we call it a weapon - right there on the table?

What I want to ask is, are they assassins? Or do they have another identity besides being obsessed with Yuhei-sama ?

[image: twins]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're Orihara Izaya's little sisters,
 [Mairu](http://myanimelist.net/character/30623/Mairu_Orihara) and 
[Kukuri](http://myanimelist.net/character/30624/Kururi_Orihara)

They appeared in the special in the first season.

Comment: To add: specifically, in the second of the two specials, i.e. "episode 25".

Answer (score 1):

If you're *super*-observant, you can actually spot Kururi and Mairu as early as episode 8 of the first season. They appear in the background of one shot (at right).

[image: Surprise! It's Kururi and Mairu!]

They aren't introduced by name, but an enterprising Japanese-reading person who recognizes Kitamura Eri's voice could take a look at the end credits and spot their names there.

[image: ep08 end credits]

It sounds to me like Mairu is just saying "Yuuhei-san" repeatedly (lol foreshadowing), but I guess Kururi must have a line that I'm not catching, too (Simon is speaking over them), since Kanemoto Hisako is credited as her in this episode.